# Gets elements from 3 dimensional array

Tags: swift

I'm new in Swift and do not know everything , i have this kind of an array

```
var arrayOFJumpForwardBack: [Int: [String: [String]]] = 
    [1: ["chapter": ["15 sec","30 sec","45 sec","60 sec"]]]
```

and , i'd like to know how can i get certain elements from this array?

Comment: What elements would you like to get?

Comment: By the way, that is not a multidimensional array. It is not an array at all. It is a dictionary. It is a dictionary whose values are dictionaries whose values are arrays.

Comment: i'm sure you are right !) i don't  know many things, i just want to know how can i manipulate with it, for example , how can i get 45 sec from it ?

Comment: 45 sec is `arrayOFJumpForwardBack[1]!["chapter"]![2]`

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'll try it , Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

### Swift - Arrays & Dictionaries

The syntax of an **array** is as follows:

```
["value1","value2","value3"]
```

The syntax of a **dictionary** is as follows:

```
["ABC":"valueForABC","XYZ":"valueForXYZ"]
```

In this case you're using a dictionary, and the main difference with the array is that the order doesn't matter, each value is represented with a key, so with the following example:

**Example:**

Let's say we have a dictionary where we have stored the word "apple" whose key is "JHC" and "pear" whose key is "IOP". We want to print "I have an apple", then:

```
var myFridge:[String:String] = ["JHC":"apple","IOP":"pear"]
print("I have an \(myFridge["JHC"]!)")
```

A **multidimensional array** is just an array inside of another, **x** dimensions you want.

I'd rather prever to create a dictionary as above ↑